# custom cursor is not working after upgrading EaselJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, easeljs

I was using EaselJS older version and in that custom cursor was working fine. I  upgrade to EaselJS 0.8.2 then only default mouse pointer is coming every time. Mouse pointer is not changing. can anyone help me to solve this?

I am using like :

```
$("canvas").css({cursor: 'url(),auto'});
```

Comment: something is missing, no? $("canvas").css({cursor: 'url(????????),auto'});

Comment: basicaly that is path of the image .$("canvas").css({cursor: 'url(/home/picture/a.cur),auto'});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With css: https://jsfiddle.net/wy75oq1g/

```
$("canvas").css("cursor", "url('http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/images2/cur106.gif'),auto");
```

With Jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/wy75oq1g/1/

Plus check if your img is load, if you are use jquery the css will be on the tag "canvas"
[image]

Comment: thanks for your quick response . I tried this solution but cursor is not changing . Still it is showing default pointer only .

Comment: Any chance you have enabled mouseover? EaselJS has some built-in cursor support, which could be overwriting yours.

Comment: try using css, check my fiddle

Comment: @Lanny: Yes I have enable mouseover on the canvas . So how to stop overwriting my cursor pointer .

Comment: @Lanny : I removed stage.enableMouseOver() and it started working fine. Can you please explain why it is like that? removal of  stage.enableMouseOver will affect performance ?

Comment: @chintanbhut Enables or disables (by passing a frequency of 0) mouse over (mouseover and mouseout) and roll over events (rollover and rollout) for this stage's display list. These events can be expensive to generate, so they are disabled by default. The frequency of the events can be controlled independently of mouse move events via the optional frequency parameter. - http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html#method_enableMouseOver

Comment: thanks for your response. for me actually  i am checking mouseover on container and displaying popup . If i enablemouse over popup is working fine but when disable that popup is not working .

Comment: Right - you won't get mouseover events if you turn this off. You can set the `cursor` of individual objects in EaselJS to change the browser cursor. This might be better than your original solution of changing the entire canvas cursor, since it will change when you are over actual interactive elements.    `myShape.cursor = "pointer";`